# Excel requires repair after adjusting .rels file

Tags: excel, vba, user-interface, ribbon

I have added a customsUI tab following the link - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/library-reference/concepts/customize-the-office-fluent-ribbon-by-using-an-open-xml-formats-file

I have added a number of additional buttons that on use call my modules, which is perfect. However after adding the following > `<Relationship Id="someID" Type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/relationships/ui/extensibility" Target="customUI/customUI.xml" />` (as per the link) to the .rels file, every time I open the xlsm Excel states it has found some problems and needs to repair. Repairing the file works and I can see and use my new customs ribbon tab, but it opens a read only copy that requires saving, once I save the document the saved version no longer shows my custom Ribbon UI and the .rels file is reset.

This is what the original .rels file looks like -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships"><Relationship Id="rDD034373-B7FD-43C3-A0CB-9279206FA87B" Type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/relationships/ui/extensibility" Target="customUI/customUI.xml"/><Relationship Id="rId3" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/extended-properties" Target="docProps/app.xml"/><Relationship Id="someID" Type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/relationships/ui/extensibility" Target="customUI/customUI.xml"/><Relationship Id="r06746EDA-A1BA-40DC-B059-3D70ED05A048" Type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/relationships/ui/extensibility" Target="customUI/customUI.xml"/><Relationship Id="r3D0ACDB6-9B04-4715-BF05-D39C9416AFCB" Type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/relationships/ui/extensibility" Target="customUI/customUI.xml"/><Relationship Id="rId2" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships/metadata/core-properties" Target="docProps/core.xml"/><Relationship Id="rId1" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/officeDocument" Target="xl/workbook.xml"/><Relationship Id="rId4" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/custom-properties" Target="docProps/custom.xml"/></Relationships>
```

This is after the adjustment -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships"><Relationship Id="rDD034373-B7FD-43C3-A0CB-9279206FA87B" Type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/relationships/ui/extensibility" Target="customUI/customUI.xml"/><Relationship Id="rId3" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/extended-properties" Target="docProps/app.xml"/><Relationship Id="someID" Type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/relationships/ui/extensibility" Target="customUI/customUI.xml"/><Relationship Id="r06746EDA-A1BA-40DC-B059-3D70ED05A048" Type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/relationships/ui/extensibility" Target="customUI/customUI.xml"/><Relationship Id="r3D0ACDB6-9B04-4715-BF05-D39C9416AFCB" Type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/relationships/ui/extensibility" Target="customUI/customUI.xml"/><Relationship Id="rId2" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships/metadata/core-properties" Target="docProps/core.xml"/><Relationship Id="rId1" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/officeDocument" Target="xl/workbook.xml"/><Relationship Id="rId4" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/custom-properties" Target="docProps/custom.xml"/><Relationship Id="someID" Type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/relationships/ui/extensibility" Target="customUI/customUI.xml" /></Relationships>
```

How would I fix the file and prevent it from repairing/opening a read only copy after I adjust the .rels file whilst still keeping my customUI additions?

Comment: could you post the content of the res file after you've added your bit? - Just a little bit before and after the part you inserted.

Comment: @Lord-JulianXLII I have added this in the edit.

Comment: There are a lot of those in your relsFile: `<Relationship Id="rDD034373-B7FD-43C3-A0CB-9279206FA87B" Type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/relationships/ui/extensibility" Target="customUI/customUI.xml"/>` - The ID looks autoGenerated - prob from the repairing. Have you tried to add your custom UI to a clean/fresh Excel Workbook. Try it and if works there you know that your current WB is corrupted.

Comment: @Lord-JulianXLII oh snap, I didin't even realise what it was doing. Yeah those relations seem to have been auto-generated at some point. Simply removing them fixes the issue. Good eyes! I was looking and didin't even notice it added additional relationships.